# Web Storage is not storing my boolean values. What could be reason for this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

This is a branch of a previous question I asked regarding filtering data tables:
[Questions regarding bootstrap tables and checkbox filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760212/questions-regarding-bootstrap-tables-and-checkbox-filtering/76762552#76762552)

I have a set of data that I pass into a Bootstrap table from my database. Each data item has  boolean, which determines if the item is visible or not in the column. This is managed by the user, who can use checkboxes to set the boolean to true or false.

```
<template>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-checkbox
            :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && field.visible"
            v-for="field in fieldsTest"
            :key="field.id"
            v-model="field.visible"
            inline>
            {{ field.label }}
          </b-checkbox>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="fieldsTest"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fieldsTest: [
      {
        key: 'userStatus',
        label: 'Status',
        sortable: true,
        sortByFormatted: true,
        visible: true

      },
      {
        key: 'userAge',
        label: 'Age',
        sortable: true,
        sortByFormatted: true,
        visible: true

      },
      {
        key: 'userName',
        label: 'Username,
        sortable: true,
        sortByFormatted: true,
        visible: true

      },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
computed: {
  visibleFields() {
    return this.fieldsTest.filter(field => field.visible)
  }
}
```

I would like to create a local storage, so that if a user has set eg. userStatus to "visible: false", then it should remain false even if the page is refreshed or if the browser is reopened.

Following the Vue documentation on the subject, I tried to set it up like this:

```
mounted() {
  localStorage.setItem( 'fieldsTest', JSON.stringify(this.fieldsTest) );
  console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'fieldsTest' ) ) );
},
```

I can see in the console that it does return a stringfied version of the fieldsTest object, but if I set one of the visible values to false and refresh the page, it does not save it.
Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on the code, you may be resetting the local storage to your default data every time the component is mounted.

You should do the opposite on mounted, set your `this.fieldsTest data = localStorage fieldsTest`, and then update `localStorage` every time you change a checkbox.

Also make sure you have considered multiple users on the same browser because they might have different visibility options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to watch the `fieldsTest` and if is there any changes in any of the object for visible property then set it into a local storage.

```
watch: {
    fieldsTest: {
      handler(newValue) {
        localStorage.setItem('fieldsTest', JSON.stringify(newValue));
      },
      deep: true
    }
}
```

Now, `In mounted()` hook, You can load the data from localStorage back into the `fieldsTest` array.

```
mounted() {
    const updatedFieldsTest = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldsTest'));
    if (updatedFieldsTest) {
      this.fieldsTest = updatedFieldsTest;
    }
}
```